# Neo4j Cypher query execution plan optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision:Profile ) 
MATCH (childD)-[:EMPLOYMENT_AS]->(root2:Employment ) 
WHERE root2.id IN ([1]) WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  
MATCH path3=(root3:Location )-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant3:Location) 
WHERE (descendant3.id IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]) OR root3.id IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35])) 
UNWIND nodes(path3) AS pathNode3 WITH childD, dg, rdgd, COLLECT(DISTINCT pathNode3) AS pathNodes3 
MATCH (childD)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(pathNode3) WHERE pathNode3 IN pathNodes3 WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  WHERE  (childD.`active` = true)  AND  (childD.`experienceMonths` >= 129)  AND ( (childD.`minSalaryUsd` <= 8883)  OR  (childD.`minHourlyRateUsd` <= 126) ) 
MATCH (childD)-[criterionRelationship8:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion {id: 2}) WHERE  (criterionRelationship8.`properties.experienceMonths` >= 1)  WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  
MATCH (childD)-[criterionRelationship10:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion {id: 36}) WHERE  (criterionRelationship10.`avgVotesWeight` >= 1.0)  AND  (criterionRelationship10.`properties.experienceMonths` >= 1)  WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  
MATCH (childD)-[criterionRelationship13:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion {id: 4}) WHERE  (criterionRelationship13.`properties.experienceMonths` >= 0)  WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  
MATCH (childD)-[criterionRelationship15:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion {id: 22}) WHERE  (criterionRelationship15.`avgVotesWeight` >= 1.0)  AND  (criterionRelationship15.`properties.experienceMonths` >= 1)  WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)  WITH childD, u, ru, dg, rdgd  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE c.id IN [2, 36, 4, 22] WITH c, childD, u, ru, dg, rdgd, (vg.avgVotesWeight * (CASE WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN coalesce({`22`:1.2236918603185925, `2`:2.9245935245152226, `36`:0.2288013749943646, `4`:3.9599506966378435}[toString(c.id)], 1.0) ELSE 1.0 END)) as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
WITH childD, u, ru , dg, rdgd , toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInteger(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes  
ORDER BY  weight  DESC , childD.createdAt DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 20 
WITH * OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[rup:UPDATED_BY]->(up:User)  
RETURN rdgd, ru, u, rup, up, childD AS decision, weight, totalVotes, [ (c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) WHERE c1.id IN [2, 36, 4, 22] | {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ] AS weightedCriteria
```

This query is automatically generated by my Cypher query builder. Right now on **1000 Profiles** the query executes **~8 seconds**.

Looks like this part of the query causes most of the issues:

```
MATCH (childD)-[:EMPLOYMENT_AS]->(root2:Employment ) 
WHERE root2.id IN ([1]) WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  
MATCH path3=(root3:Location )-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant3:Location) 
WHERE (descendant3.id IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]) OR root3.id IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35])) 
UNWIND nodes(path3) AS pathNode3 WITH childD, dg, rdgd, COLLECT(DISTINCT pathNode3) AS pathNodes3 
MATCH (childD)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(pathNode3) WHERE pathNode3 IN pathNodes3 WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd
```

Is there a way to optimize this?

This is `PROFILE` output:

**UPDATED**

I reimplemented initial part of the query to the following:

```
WITH [] as ceNodeList  MATCH (root2:Employment ) 
WHERE root2.id IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]) 
WITH ceNodeList, root2, COLLECT(root2) AS listRoot2 
WITH apoc.coll.unionAll(ceNodeList, listRoot2) AS ceNodeList 
WITH apoc.coll.toSet(ceNodeList) as ceNodeList  
MATCH (root3:Location ) 
WHERE root3.id IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73]) 
WITH ceNodeList, root3, COLLECT(root3) AS listRoot3 
OPTIONAL MATCH (root3)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant3:Location)
OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant3:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(root3) 
WITH ceNodeList, listRoot3, COLLECT( DISTINCT ascendant3) AS listAscendant3, COLLECT( DISTINCT descendant3) AS listDescendant3
WITH listRoot3, listAscendant3, apoc.coll.unionAll(ceNodeList, apoc.coll.unionAll(listDescendant3, apoc.coll.unionAll(listRoot3, listAscendant3))) AS ceNodeList 
WITH apoc.coll.toSet(ceNodeList) as ceNodeList  
UNWIND ceNodeList AS ceNode 
WITH DISTINCT ceNode MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision:Profile ) -[:REQUIRES]->(ceNode) 
WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd, collect(ceNode) as ceNodes 
WITH childD, dg, rdgd, ceNodes, reduce(ceNodeLabels = [], n IN ceNodes | ceNodeLabels + labels(n)) as ceNodeLabels  
WHERE all(x IN ['Employment', 'Location'] 
WHERE x IN ceNodeLabels) WITH childD,  dg, rdgd return count(childD)
```

Now it works several times faster, but still not perfect. Is there something I may do in order to improve this?

**UPDATED1**

```
WITH [] as ceNodeList  
MATCH (root2:Location ) 
WHERE root2.id IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]) 
WITH ceNodeList, root2 
OPTIONAL MATCH (root2)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant2:Location) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant2:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(root2) 
WITH ceNodeList, COLLECT(root2) AS listRoot2, COLLECT( DISTINCT ascendant2) AS listAscendant2, COLLECT( DISTINCT descendant2) AS listDescendant2 
WITH apoc.coll.union(ceNodeList, apoc.coll.union(listDescendant2, apoc.coll.union(listRoot2, listAscendant2))) AS ceNodeList 
WITH ceNodeList  MATCH (root3:Employment ) 
WHERE root3.id IN ([101, 102, 103, 104, 105]) 
WITH ceNodeList, COLLECT(root3) AS listRoot3 
WITH apoc.coll.union(ceNodeList, listRoot3) AS ceNodeList 
WITH ceNodeList  
UNWIND ceNodeList as seNode 
WITH collect(seNode.id) as seNodeIds with apoc.coll.toSet(seNodeIds) as seNodeIds  
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Profile ) -[:REQUIRES]->(ceNode) 
WHERE ceNode.id in seNodeIds 
WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd, collect(ceNode) as ceNodes 
WITH childD, dg, rdgd, ceNodes, reduce(ceNodeLabels = [], n IN ceNodes | ceNodeLabels + labels(n)) as ceNodeLabels  
WHERE all(x IN ['Employment', 'Location'] 
WHERE x IN ceNodeLabels) 
WITH childD,  dg, rdgd
```

Comment: This seems to be the bottleneck `(root3:Location )-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant3:Location)`, matching all the locations and their connectivity, and then filtering them out using IN operator.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to optimize this? I need to check that `childD` variable to `:LOCATED_IN` `Locations` (with provided `IDs`) or their descendants

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35] AS ids
WITH reduce(idsMap = {}, x IN ids | apoc.map.setEntry(idsMap, toString(x), true))
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision:Profile ) 
MATCH (childD)-[:EMPLOYMENT_AS]->(root2:Employment ) 
WHERE root2.id = 1 
WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd, idsMap
MATCH (descendant3:Location) WHERE apoc.map.get(idsMap, toString(descendant3.id), false) = true
MATCH path3=(root3:Location )-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant3) 
WHERE apoc.map.get(idsMap, toString(root3.id), false) = true
UNWIND nodes(path3) AS pathNode3 WITH childD, dg, rdgd, COLLECT(DISTINCT pathNode3) AS pathNodes3 
MATCH (childD)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(pathNode3) WHERE pathNode3 IN pathNodes3 WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  WHERE  (childD.`active` = true)  AND  (childD.`experienceMonths` >= 129)  AND ( (childD.`minSalaryUsd` <= 8883)  OR  (childD.`minHourlyRateUsd` <= 126) ) 
MATCH (childD)-[criterionRelationship8:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion {id: 2}) WHERE  (criterionRelationship8.`properties.experienceMonths` >= 1)  WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  
MATCH (childD)-[criterionRelationship10:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion {id: 36}) WHERE  (criterionRelationship10.`avgVotesWeight` >= 1.0)  AND  (criterionRelationship10.`properties.experienceMonths` >= 1)  WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  
MATCH (childD)-[criterionRelationship13:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion {id: 4}) WHERE  (criterionRelationship13.`properties.experienceMonths` >= 0)  WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  
MATCH (childD)-[criterionRelationship15:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion {id: 22}) WHERE  (criterionRelationship15.`avgVotesWeight` >= 1.0)  AND  (criterionRelationship15.`properties.experienceMonths` >= 1)  WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)  WITH childD, u, ru, dg, rdgd  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE c.id IN [2, 36, 4, 22] WITH c, childD, u, ru, dg, rdgd, (vg.avgVotesWeight * (CASE WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN coalesce({`22`:1.2236918603185925, `2`:2.9245935245152226, `36`:0.2288013749943646, `4`:3.9599506966378435}[toString(c.id)], 1.0) ELSE 1.0 END)) as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
WITH childD, u, ru , dg, rdgd , toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInteger(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes  
ORDER BY  weight  DESC , childD.createdAt DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 20 
WITH * OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[rup:UPDATED_BY]->(up:User)  
RETURN rdgd, ru, u, rup, up, childD AS decision, weight, totalVotes, [ (c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) WHERE c1.id IN [2, 36, 4, 22] | {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ] AS weightedCriteria
```

Here, I have created a map from the `ids` given and then used it instead of IN operator.

Update:

I think your new query can be simplified a bit. We can combine `apoc.coll.unionAll` and `apoc.coll.toSet`, with a single call to `apoc.coll.union`, try this:

```
MATCH (root2:Employment) 
WHERE root2.id IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]) 
WITH COLLECT(root2) AS ceNodeList 
MATCH (root3:Location) 
WHERE root3.id IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73]) 
WITH ceNodeList, root3, COLLECT(root3) AS listRoot3 
OPTIONAL MATCH (root3)-[:CONTAINS*0..]-(descendants:Location)
WITH ceNodeList, listRoot3, COLLECT(DISTINCT descendant3) AS listDescendant3
WITH apoc.coll.union(ceNodeList, apoc.coll.union(listDescendant3, listRoot3)) AS ceNodeList   
UNWIND ceNodeList AS ceNode 
WITH DISTINCT ceNode MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision:Profile)-[:REQUIRES]->(ceNode) 
WITH DISTINCT childD, dg, rdgd, collect(ceNode) as ceNodes 
WITH childD, dg, rdgd, ceNodes, reduce(ceNodeLabels = [], n IN ceNodes | ceNodeLabels + labels(n)) as ceNodeLabels  
WHERE all(x IN ['Employment', 'Location'] 
WHERE x IN ceNodeLabels) WITH childD,  dg, rdgd return count(childD)
```

Comment: Thanks! The main issue here that I may have absolutelly random IDs

Comment: ohh ok, we can try to fix that, but did this ran any faster?

Comment: Updated with a variant try it now.

Comment: @alexanoid Can you please share the query runtime after optimization? It helps in my learning. Thanks.

Comment: please see my updated question. This is the best I have so far but still not perfect

Comment: Updated the answer with a new query. Please try it out

Comment: Thank you! The query plan doesn't change a lot. Is there anything else we may try in order to improve?

Comment: Simplified a bit more, given the context, I think this is the best possible.

Comment: Thank you! Please see my updated question, I reworked the query at the very end. Removed duplicates from the `ceNodeList` . For some reason it had arrays as a list elements. Now this is the best result I have ever had with this query

Comment: You can combine `OPTIONAL MATCH (root2)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant2:Location) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant2:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(root2)` these two matches into a single one like this `OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant2:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]-(root2)`, this will reduce internal cartesian products and should be optimal. Try the second query in my answer, it is updated to follow this.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work properly and it returns a lot more locations than I expected because of multi-parent Location entity